# Can't get data from request with ajax

Tags: ajax

Trying to get data from a database request with ajax

As you can seen bellow. Codes are basic ajax and sql request codes, there is no complicated things. But my result is allways null.

I need help, thanks

PS: Sorry for my english

Ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#ligue").change(function(){
                var Ligue_Name=$(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "pages/test.php",
                        data: {Ligue_Name:Ligue_Name},
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html){
                            $("#club").html(html);
                        } 
                    });
                });
        });
```

test.php

```
<?php
    global $db;

    $output = '';

    $req = $db->query(
        "SELECT * FROM club WHERE Ligue_Name LIKE ".$_POST['Ligue_Name']."         
    ");

    $output .= '<option value="" disabled selected>Select Ligue</option>';
    if(mysqli_num_rows($req)>0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($req)) {
            $output .= '<option value="'.$_POST["club"].'">'.$row["club"].'</option>';
        }
    }
    echo $output;
    
?>
```

Comment: Try to wrap your code inside' if(isset($_POST["club"]))' and check if it print out any thing

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried and it dosen't work

Comment: So issue lies in $_POST["club"], remove it from your code as its not defined,

Comment: I have 2 select, one for "ligue" and an other one for "club" (who actually is empty). I made an ajax request to get all every clubs for the active ligue's value. Maybe it's not clear

Comment: i tried your code and its working fine, I am curious to know why its not working on your side, I am using chrome for testing your code. I am pasting my code as answer, check and let me know

Comment: I just resolve my problem. Thanks for your help @NaturalCoder

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="club"></div><br />
  <input type="text" id="ligue" >
  <button type="button" id="addline" onclick="league();">+</button>
  <script>
            function league(){

                var Ligue_Name=$("#ligue").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "pages/test.php",
                        data: {Ligue_Name:Ligue_Name},
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html){
                            $("#club").html(html);
                        } 
                    });
                };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Your test.php,

```
<?php
    global $db;

    $output = '';

    $req = $db->query(
        "SELECT * FROM club WHERE Ligue_Name LIKE ".$_POST['Ligue_Name']."         
    ");

    $output .= '<option value="" disabled selected>Select Ligue</option>';
    if(mysqli_num_rows($req)>0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($req)) {
            $output .= '<option value="Testing">'.$row["club"].'</option>';
        }
    }
    echo $output;
    
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it dosen't work for me. There is my code:

Answer (score 0):

Test.php

```
if($_POST["ligue"]){

        global $db;

        $output = '';

        $req = $db->query(
            "SELECT * FROM club WHERE Ligue_Name LIKE ".$_POST['Ligue_Name']."         
        ");

        $output .= '<option value="" disabled selected>Select Ligue</option>';
        if(mysqli_num_rows($req)>0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($req)) {
                $output .= '<option value="'.$_POST["name"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option>';
            }
        }
        echo $output;
    }
```

my.html

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <select class="custom-select" id="ligue" name="ligue">
        <option selected disabled>Selectionnez votre ligue</option>
        <?
        $clubs = getClub();
        foreach ($clubs as $club) {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $club->Ligue_Name ?>"><?php echo $club->Ligue_Name ?></option>
        <?
            }

        ?>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <label class="input-group-text" for="club">Club</label>
  </div>
  <select class="custom-select" id="club" name="club" required>
  </select>
</div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#ligue").change(function(){
                var Ligue_Name=$(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "pages/test.php",
                        data: {Ligue_Name:Ligue_Name},
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html){
                            $("#club").html(html);
                        } 
                    });
                });
        });
  </script>
```